# How do I install indicator-workspace?

Tags: indicator, 13.04, workspaces

I receive this error when I install the software.

Basically I want to know which space am I working on.

```
$sudo apt-get install indicator-workspaces
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package indicator-workspaces is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'indicator-workspaces' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: did you `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, indicator-workspaces isn't necessary anymore, in 13.04, because the standard workspace switcher icon shows which workspace you're in, however, you have to enable the workspace switcher in the first place.

Comment: yes, you are right. I also found it.

Comment: Does not work with rotate cube however...

Answer (score 0):

for ubuntu 13.04
go to this  link
[indicator-workspaces download](http://ppa.launchpad.net/geod/ppa-geod/ubuntu/pool/main/i/indicator-workspaces/)

open the ubuntu software center search for python-wnck , installed the library or use the following command

```
apt-get install python-wnck
```

install the downloaded deb file

```
dpkg -i indicator-workspaces_0.6.4_all.deb
```

start the indicator-workspaces

```
indicator-workspaces &
```

for other options left click on the indicator panel

I have tested in the ubuntu 13.04 and its working

Comment: That PPA has packages for Lucic, Maverick, Natty and Oneiric but not for Raring (13.04). In addition, packages from a PPa shouldn't be installed with direct download as you wouldn't get any updates for them.

Comment: yup i know that.. just answered here if anyone has the same problem who uses more than 5 workspaces and badly needs to indicator-workspace to run

Answer (score 0):

As answer is already given by other users , I am posting this to let other users know that I have tested indicator-workspace on 14.04 LTS and 15.04 and its working fine.[image: On ubuntu 15.04 indicator-workspace]

Answer (score -1):

1. Right click on the Bottom Panel.
2. Select Add to panel
3. Search for Workspace Switcher and Add it to the Panel.

Comment: I am gathering this isn't for Unity which is the default.